# C# BindingList<> not updating a WPF Listbox on changed items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am on a MVVM C# project.

I want to display a list of objects.
I want to add and remove items in this list and ALSO change items in this list.

So I choosed the BindingList<> over the ObservableCollection<>, which would not get noticed if an item has changed. 
(I also tested the ObservableCollectionEx which is out there in the web, but this has the same behavior like the BindingList for me).
But the Listbox is not changing when items are changed.
(Adding and removing items is updated in the Listbox)

In my XAML

```
<ListBox  DisplayMemberPath="NameIndex" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile}">
```

or alternative with the ItemTemplate

```
<ListBox  DockPanel.Dock="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameIndex}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In my ViewModel (ViewModelBase is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged etc)

```
public class ProfileListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{    
    private BindingList<Profile> profiles;
    public BindingList<Profile> Profiles
    {
        get
        {
            return profiles;
        }
        set
        {
            profiles = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My items are also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and I am calling OnPropertyChanged("Name") in my Setters.

My model

```
public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Profile(){}

    public int ProfileID { get; set; }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Wiring the View with the ViewModel (BindingList is initialized before View)

```
ProfileListViewModel plvw= new ProfileListViewModel(message.Content);
var profileView = new ProfileListView(plvw);
profileView.ShowDialog();
```

In the View.xaml.cs

```
public ProfileListView(ProfileListViewModel plvw)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = plvw;
}
```

When I am changing the name of an object then I get the ListChanged event to which I have subscribted in my ViewModel (`Profiles.ListChanged += Profiles_ListChanged;`) for testing BUT the items in the ListBox are NOT changing.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I get a updated Listbox?

Comment: NameIndex doesn't exist in Profile type. Do you see any text in ListBox items?

Comment: The DisplayMemberPath should be "Name" - not "NameIndex"

Comment: How and where are you setting the Name property of a Profile object? And what is "NameIndex"?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, using your code as fat as shown above my ListBox gets updated both when Adding items and when changing items. I suspect the problem migth be the way you set the DataContext for the view, could you show the relevant parts of your `ProfileListView.xaml` and `ProfileListView.xaml.cs`?

Comment: NameIndex is a other parameter of the Profile object.... And yes I can see objects in the listbox. I can add and remove Profiles, which ist updated. But when I change the Name of a Profile,  which ist part of the NameIndex field, in a Textbox which is populated over the SelectedItem of the listbox, the parameter is changed in the BindingList, the ListChanged Event fires but the UI ist not updated.

Comment: If you want someone to know what's wrong with your code, you will have to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you are seeing. That said, your reason for choosing `BindingList<T>` over `ObservableCollection<T>` seems specious to me. The collection isn't what handles updates of individual items. Rather, a template used to display items in the view gets bound for each item, and property-change notifications for each item get observed by the appropriate template view instance. This works as well for `ObservableCollection<T>` as for `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: Some tips: if you have an item template on the listbox which presents the name then check your binding; check the listchanged event arguments to see in detail what kind of ListChangedType raises; try to force a ResetItem on the binding list after changing the name; as others mentioned no need for BindingList, ObservableCollection should do the trick.

Comment: I have added the constructor of the View... @MaSiMan

Comment: Maybe thats not the point but, if I use a ObserveableCollection and I change a Item I do not get a CollectionChanged event. With the BindingList ListChanged Event is fired...

Comment: @ChevulErvin when I force a ResetItem for the changed Item the UI is still not updated.

Comment: @PeterDuniho can you please give me an example of such a template which is bound to each item?

Comment: _"I use a ObserveableCollection and I change a Item I do not get a CollectionChanged event"_ -- why do you want a `CollectionChanged` event when it's not the collection, but rather an element of the collection, which has changed? _"can you please give me an example of such a template which is bound to each item?"_ -- surely you can use your favorite web search and/or the Stack Overflow search to find discussion of using `ItemTemplate` in an `ItemControl`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have changed from DisplayMemberPath to ItemTemplate, which does not change a thing. (added a alternative source in the original post)

Comment: A template works only if it's compatible with the type you're displaying. I don't see any `NameIndex` property anywhere in the code you posted, so not only would you not get updated if and when such a property changed, it wouldn't even show any data in the first place. Maybe you meant to write `Name` instead?

Comment: You should really post the code for NameIndex. I assume this is a computed property, and what you need to do is call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameIndex))` in the setter for Name.

Comment: @MaSiMan thx that was the hint ... I was changing Name and a Index, which where not raising OnPropertyChanged("NameIndex") which is the DisplayMember

Comment: You are welcome - I posted this as an answer. If this works for you, it would be great if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your DisplayIndex is the computed property `NameIndex`, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("NameIndex")` when its value changes due to a change in other properties, e.g.:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        OnPropertyChanged("NameIndex");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
Profiles.ResetBindings() to bind it again.